# How to handle Stormpath ID Site JWT response

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, stormpath

I'm trying to create an ASP.NET application with Stormpath ID Site authorization. I create request and response action and successfully got the account.

But what next? How to tell the application that the user is authenticated?

```
public async Task<RedirectResult> Callback(string jwtResponse)
{
    var client = Request.GetStormpathClient();
    var app = await client.GetApplicationAsync(appUrl);
    var requestDescriptor = HttpRequests.NewRequestDescriptor()
    .WithMethod("GET")
    .WithUri("http://localhost:50084/Auth/Callback?jwtResponse=" + jwtResponse)
    .Build();
    var idSiteListener = app.NewIdSiteAsyncCallbackHandler(requestDescriptor);
    var accountResult = await idSiteListener.GetAccountResultAsync();
    var account = accountResult.GetAccountAsync().Result; //Account
    //What I must do here to tell application that user is authenticated
    return Redirect("/");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of getting the account from the ID Site response, you could exchange the JWT for a Stormpath access token:

```
public async Task<RedirectResult> Callback(string jwtResponse)
{
    var client = Request.GetStormpathClient();
    var app = await client.GetApplicationAsync(appUrl);

    var exchangeRequest = new StormpathTokenGrantRequest
    {
        Token = jwtResponse
    });

    var grantResponse = await application.ExecuteOauthRequestAsync(exchangeRequest);

    // Return grantResponse.AccessTokenString in a secure HTTPOnly cookie, or as a JSON response
}
```

If you use the [Stormpath ASP.NET plugin](https://docs.stormpath.com/dotnet/aspnet/latest/quickstart.html), you can [enable ID Site](https://docs.stormpath.com/dotnet/aspnet/latest/id_site.html) and this will be handled for you automatically.

Disclaimer: I'm the package author.